# Does padded rows (fake inputs) affect backpropagation?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, backpropagation

Each row data doesn't have the same size. It looks like this:

Ideally, the shape of input data will be: `(batch_size, N, dim)`

But each row in the batch is not equal dimension. E.g: it can be `(k, dim)` k < N

To feed to my model I have to add some fake rows called padded rows.

These inputs go through some functions, layers in my model.

In the end, the loss function takes the mean of each row as input -> `(batch_size, dim)` . But I don't want to consider the padded row in the reduction.

-> So I computed the mean as:

- assigned all the padded rows to zero.
- `torch.sum(..)/(number_of_non_padded_rows)`

My question is: As the padded rows is included in the parameter of function torch.sum(...), does the model try to modify the weights base on these fake (padded) rows?
My second thought is because I assigned the padded row by a constraint value which is zero, then it somehow get rid of gradients of these padded rows during training?

Edit:
Base on chain rule, derivative of constraint number is zero so I guess my second thought is correct and my approach is correct

Comment: This is related a bit to the concept of dropout. Dropout is when you take a layer and for each neuron give a random chance that the neuron will just output zero. It's said that in dropout, if a node is dropped then [its associated output weights are considered to have zero influence on the output](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/38310/72218), and therefore won't be considered during backprop.